# code crashing at malloc() on windows XP

Tags: c, malloc

My simplified code looks like something below:

```
 char decrypted[64] = "P@ssw0rd                ";
 int realsize = 8;
  realloc(decrypted, realsize);

  char *dec2 = (char *) malloc(realsize+1); // Exe crashes at this point
```

I am guessing it has to do with **char *dec2**  , but this only crashes Win XP for some reason.

Comment: I've retagged the question as C because it does not contain C++ code.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - the fact that the malloc was typecast was C++, in C that's unneeded. If I tell OP not to typecast malloc now (which shouldn't be done in C) but OP is really building C++ code (g++) it will lead to an error.

Comment: @Mike The quoted code is compilable as either C or C++ and yes, the cast is needed only in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot `realloc()` what hasn't been allocated with `malloc()` or `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

Comment: I see, but why does my exe only crash on Xp machines.

Comment: Pure luck, nothing else. What you're trying to do is categorized as "undefined behavior" by the language standard and you cannot reason about it. UB is bad and to be avoided, that's all you need to know about it besides knowing when something constitutes UB.

Comment: ...because calling `realloc()` on stack arrays is "undefined behavior" -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html -- so the C runtime can do whatever it wants, including *not* crashing.

Answer (score 2):

`decrypted` is an array allocated on the stack. `realloc` can only re-allocate memory allocated on the heap with `malloc` or `calloc`.